# Algorithm for finding coefficients in linear combination of two numbers which is equal to their gcd

Tags: algorithm, implementation

Could someone, please, help me to come up with the algorithm for finding coefficients in linear combination of two numbers which is equal to their gcd?

I know the idea behind it. I should proceed with the Euclidian algorithm and find gcd and then I should go back substituting values, while I won't get a representation of my gcd.

I do not need an idea (in case it is not different from mine, which was described above) and I do not need implementation (I will do it myself). But what I need are details. I can not figure out how I can store values from the Euclidian algorithm and then go through all of them  and represent the gcd as a linear combination at the end. Should I use an array or are there some better recommendations?

Comment: Since you don't know the size of your collection beforefand I'd take a list rather than an array to store the values of the Euclidean algorithm. Lists are better if the size chnges often, but the values inside the list stay the same, arrays ar better if the size is constant, but the values are changed often

Comment: @user2887596, thanks. Got it.

Comment: Here are all the details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: @Henry, it is very nice. I think it is sufficient for my problem. Thanks a lot.